# Compile with Apache Flex SDK4.8.0, AIR3.4 and FDT5.6.2 yields "unable to open '{airHome}/frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc'"

Tags: android, ios, sdk, air, fdt

I downloaded the Apache Flex 4.8.0 SDK and added the TLFTextField and OSMF dependencies. I then installed the SDK into FDT 5.6.2 and merged the AIR 3.4 SDK into the newly added SDK with no complaints.

I updated the AIR app descriptors to accommodate the bump of AIR 3.3 to AIR 3.4, the projects yields no errors nor warnings.

Doing a debug compile for iOS outputs the following: (Note the ERROR line)

```
Starting Full Build of SteadyEddieApp.
Compiler arguments:
  -output 
    D:\steady-eddie-app\bin\SteadyEddieApp.swf
  -+configname=air +flexlib=
    D:\utils-adobe\flex-sdks\4.8.0.win\frameworks
  --compiler.debug=true
  --debug-password=
  --compiler.source-path+=
    D:\steady-eddie-app\src,
    D:\steady-eddie-app\src_3rdParty
  --compiler.library-path+=
    D:\utils-adobe\flex-sdks\4.8.0.win\frameworks\libs\air\airglobal.swc,
    D:\utils-adobe\flex-sdks\4.8.0.win\frameworks\libs\core.swc,
    D:\utils-adobe\flex-sdks\4.8.0.win\frameworks\libs\osmf.swc,
    D:\utils-adobe\flex-sdks\4.8.0.win\frameworks\libs\textLayout.swc,
    D:\utils-adobe\flex-sdks\4.8.0.win\frameworks\libs\air\servicemonitor.swc,
    D:\steady-eddie-app\lib\Assets.swc,
    D:\steady-eddie-app\lib\as3-signals-v0.9-BETA.swc,
    D:\steady-eddie-app\lib\greensock.swc,
    D:\steady-eddie-app\lib\robotlegs-framework-v1.5.2.swc,
    D:\steady-eddie-app\lib\AssetLoader-v2.5.1.swc,
    D:\steady-eddie-app\lib\gestouch-0.4-alpha.swc
  -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=
    true
  -target-player=11.1
  -library-path+=
    D:\utils-adobe\flex-sdks\4.8.0.win/frameworks/locale/en_US
  -default-size=550,400
  -- 
    D:\steady-eddie-app\src\com\steadyeddieworld\app\SteadyEddieApp.as

INFO Loading configuration file D:\utils-adobe\flex-sdks\4.8.0.win\frameworks\air-config.xml

ERROR D:\utils-adobe\flex-sdks\4.8.0.win\frameworks\air-config.xml[64]:
unable to open '{airHome}/frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc'

      </external-library-path>
^

Pure build time: 246 ms. 
Save compiler information in 2 ms. 
Clean compiler information in 0 ms. 
Could not create file D:\steady-eddie-app\bin\SteadyEddieApp.swf.
Build failed.
```

Not sure what's causing the problem, any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`</external-library-path>` has to do with the compiler configuration. I would guess something get misconfigured when trying to assemble the SDK by hand.

Try using the [Apache Flex installer](http://incubator.apache.org/flex/installer.html). It will set it up for you.

...side note:

> I updated the AIR app descriptors...

Why did you do this?  I don't believe anything changed in the basic descriptor from AIR 3.3 3.4. Also, merging the SDK will automatically update the template - descriptor files. FDT will draw the latest from the AIR SDK which is installed.

That may not be an issue in your case, but it is interesting....

Comment: Thanks Alan, I used the installer to download/create the sdk and used FDT to merge AIR 3.4 into the sdk. Everything works now, seems my manual process did mess something up. :)

Comment: PS: The "app descriptors" files I'm talking about are the XML files for the AIR app config. When you update your AIR sdk you have to match that version in your app-xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try the steps here that include editing the env-template.properties file (renaming it env.properties) to change the airHome environment variable.

http://lucamezzalira.com/2012/07/24/how-to-install-flex-4-8-0-sdk-in-flash-builder/

I should add.  I'm trying to do the same with the new Apache Flex SDK 4.9 release and AIR 3.5.

I gather that instead of doing an overlay install as was recommended to ver 4.7 the new convention is to use a separate location for the Flex SDK and the AIR SDK and to tell the Flex SDK where to find the AIR SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Apache Flex 4.9.0 installer will install AIR 3.4 as part of the installation process.

The installer can be found at http://flex.apache.org/installer.html.

If you want to use AIR 3.5 or 3.6 you can create a SDK by changing the path to the ADOBE_AIR_SDK_MAC_URL / ADOBE_AIR_SDK_WIN_URL and the ADOBE_FB_GLOBALPLAYER_SWC_URL in 
/ide/flashbuilder/makeApacheFlexForFlashbuilder.sh (on Mac) or /ide/flashbuilder/makeApacheFlexForFlashbuilder.bat (on Windows) and running the script.

While the script is called makeApacheFlexForFlashbuilder it will work for any IDE that supports the (Apache) Flex SDK.